# How to check if an array has the value one after another in other array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have been a facing a problem in my project. Here is the case

Suppose I have two arrays, `array_1`, `array_2`. `array_1` has value of `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']` and `array_2` has value of `['B', 'C', 'D']`. I want the result to true if `array_1` has the same value of `array_2` one after another. For the above case is true. Now if `array_2` has a value of `['C', 'D', 'B']`, Then it returns to false because the value is not one after another. Here is the code what I tried

```
    if (!array_diff($array_2, $array_1)) {
        return true;
    }
return false
```

But this does not return what I want to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use array unique

Comment: @RameshS I dont think array unique could satisfy my need

Comment: Do you want unique values from both array? What do you want?

Comment: Do the arrays have to be the same length or can compare against a fragment of an array so long as the order is the same?

Comment: First use array_intersect on array_1 and then use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353683/most-efficient-way-to-compare-arrays-in-php-by-order

Comment: No I dont want unique value. I want either true / false if the first array has the element of the second array one after anther

Comment: @Joseph_J No the two arrays has not the same length

Comment: @HabibHassan You can make your own custom algorithm for that using basic `foreach` and `if else`

Comment: @HabibHassan check this out https://3v4l.org/0EgPq

Comment: @HabibHassan should ['B', 'D', 'E'] return true or false?

Comment: @Nick  ['B', 'D', 'E'] should return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit 3:**

As Nick pointed out, this wouldn't work in some cases. Like `$a = ['a-b', 'c']; $b = ['a', 'b'];`.

Go see his solution.

This *doesn't always* work:

```
$array_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
$array_2 = ['B', 'C', 'D'];

if (str_contains(implode('-', $array_1), implode('-', $array_2))) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Or simply:

```
return str_contains(implode('-', $array_1), implode('-', $array_2));
```

I imploded arrays (making them a string and gluing them with `-`) and checked if the string of `$array_2` is a substring of `$array_1`'s string with Laravel's [str_contains(haystack, needle)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-contains)

Comment: True. This won't work. `str_contains` is Laravel's helper. The question has a Laravel tag

Comment: This is better with adding the glue. It still could have issues if values have the glue character in them or if values in `$array_2` are substrings of values in `$array_1` e.g. if `$array_1 = ['A', 'BB', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];` it will return true.

Comment: The new version won't work if for example `$array_1 = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];` and `$array_2 = ['C', 'D', 'E'];` :-(

Comment: Oh of course. Eh I'm going to sleep. Cool problem, I'm sure there's some really nice solution that we're missing. But not tonight. Keeping up because I think my original solution is really nice if you know that the strings would only be 1 character long.

Comment: I believe the solution I posted (using `json_encode`) solves that robustness issue while retaining the simplicity, but I guess OP doesn't need it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function which will robustly check that the values in `$array_2` are in `$array_1` in the same order, *one after the other* (i.e. with sequential indexes):

```
function compare_arrays($array_1, $array_2) {
    $count_1 = count($array_1);
    $count_2 = count($array_2);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_1 - $count_2 + 1; $i++) {
        if ($array_1[$i] == $array_2[0]) {
            for ($j = 1; $j < $count_2 && $i + $j < $count_1; $j++) {
                if ($array_1[$i+$j] != $array_2[$j]) break;
            }
            if ($j == $count_2) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$array_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
$array_2 = ['B', 'C', 'D'];
echo compare_arrays($array_1, $array_2) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
$array_2 = ['C', 'D', 'B'];
echo compare_arrays($array_1, $array_2) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
$array_2 = ['B', 'D', 'E'];
echo compare_arrays($array_1, $array_2) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
$array_2 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
echo compare_arrays($array_1, $array_2) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
$array_1 = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
$array_2 = ['C', 'D', 'E'];
echo compare_arrays($array_1, $array_2) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
```

Output:

```
true 
false 
false 
true 
true
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZHo2p)

Answer (score 3):

Unless I missed something, you can simply do this:

```
$result = strpos(
  implode(array_map('json_encode', $input1)), 
  implode(array_map('json_encode', $input2))
) !== false;
```

This basically transforms each input into a string where every value is JSON-encoded, then checks whether the second one is part of the first one.

**Demo here: https://3v4l.org/eAQst**

Answer (score 0):

I liked this question and I liked the different solutions.  I know I'm late to the party but here is my attempt at it.  I don't know how it compares in terms of cost with big data sets but this should be quite robust.

My attempt just iterates across each element and then creates a second array of the same size as the searched array and then does a comparison check at the end.

Code:

```
function checkArray($a, $b){

  $test = FALSE;

  for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++){

    for($j = 0; $j < count($b); $j++){

      $array[] = $a[$i + $j];

    }

    if($array == $b){

      $test = TRUE;
      break;

    }

    unset($array);

  }

return $test;

}


$sample = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
$match = ['B', 'C', 'D'];
echo checkArray($sample, $match) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; //True
$match = ['C', 'D', 'B'];
echo checkArray($sample, $match) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; //False
$match = ['B', 'D', 'E'];
echo checkArray($sample, $match) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; //False
$match = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
echo checkArray($sample, $match) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; //True
$match = ['A'];
echo checkArray($sample, $match) ? "true\n" : "false\n"; //True
$match = ['F'];
echo checkArray($sample, $match) ? "true\n" : "false\n";//True
$sample = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
$match = ['C', 'D', 'E'];
echo checkArray($sample, $match) ? "true\n" : "false\n";//True
$sample = ['C', 'D', 'E'];
$match = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
echo checkArray($sample, $match) ? "true\n" : "false\n";//False
```

This will output:

```
true
false
false
true
true
true
true
false
```